# Prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{p_n-n(\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))-1)} = \infty$

Tags: calculus, solution-verification

I try to prove a limit on prime numbers and logarithm, I want to know whether my proof is correct.

We write $\ln_2$ instead of $\ln(\ln(n))$.
Let $p_n$ denotes the $n^{th}$ prime number.
The purpose is to prove that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{p_n-n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1)} = \infty$

In 1999 Pierre Dusart showed that:
$n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1)<p_n<n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-0.9484)$ for $n \geq 39017$

It is also proved that:
$p_n \leq n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1+\frac{\ln_2(n)-2}{\ln(n)})$ for $n \geq 688383$

We deduce:

$n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1+\frac{\ln_2(n)-2}{\ln(n)})-n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1 \geq p_n-n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1)$ for $n \geq 688383$

Hence:

$\frac{n}{n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1+\frac{\ln_2(n)-2}{\ln(n)})-n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1)} \leq \frac{n}{p_n-n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1)}$ for $n \geq 688383$

We have:

$\frac{n}{n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1+\frac{\ln_2(n)-2}{\ln(n)})-n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1)} = \frac{n}{\frac{n\ln_2(n)-2}{\ln(n)}}$

$\frac{n}{\frac{n\ln_2(n)-2}{\ln(n)}} = \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln_2(n)-2}$

And:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{\ln(n)}{\ln_2(n)-2} = \infty$

Because:

$\frac{n}{n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1+\frac{\ln_2(n)-2}{\ln(n)})-n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1)} \leq \frac{n}{p_n-n(\ln(n)+\ln_2(n)-1)}$ for $n \geq 688383$

We deduce:

$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{p_n-n(\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))-1)} = \infty$

Answer (score 2):

Your proof looks fine, but you can significantly simplify using only the result from Dusart. Note that

$$n(\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))-1)<p_n<n(\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))-0.9)$$

Implies

$$0<p_n-n(\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))-1)$$

$$<n(\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))-0.9)-n(\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))-1)=.1$$

Then

$$\frac{n}{p_n-n(\ln(n)+\ln(\ln(n))-1)}>\frac{n}{.1}=10n$$